# Insert like/dislike buttons with embedded videos of YouTube

Tags: angular, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I already know how to embed a YouTube video inside an Angular application (there are many answers on Stackoverflow on the subject) but what about embedding also the "like/dislike" buttons?

There is a way?

[image: like/dislike buttons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the straight-forward way that you can embed a video, but using the [`getRating`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating) API endpoint, you can get the number of likes and dislikes, and using the [`rate`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) endpoint, you can update the values.